# Keyboard shortcut for going to the next automatically boxed parameter in editor?

Tags: texstudio, editors

I am using TeXstudio and whenever I insert a LaTeX function such as `\frac{num}{den}` by typing in the first few letters (e.g."\fr") and pressing enter for autocompletion, it puts the parameters, in this example `den` and `num`, in boxes. The first parameter is automatically highlighted. Is there a way to jump to/highlight the next parameter?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can change the default shortcut using *Options* menu and *Configure TeXstudio*.

The default is **Alt+Right Arrow** (see the image below: *Next Placeholder*).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah! Thank you for your quick and detailed reply. Works perfectly. It was set to <none> by default for me.

Comment: @user1961781, by the way, welcome to TeX.SE.